# How to have a variable in 2 php pages?

Tags: php, variables

Getting a variable for 2pages

I want to hash my string. Then I want to get hash var from my first page to 2nd page.

I made 2 pages.

```
 1.php

 2.php
```

In page 1 I wrote these codes

```
  <?php

$text = "mypassword123and";

// here i want to hash my String

$hash = hash('sha256', $text);

?>
```

Here I want to have `$hash` at my page 2

I can't get the var by this

```
echo "$hash";
```

How can I solve that?

Comment: i just want to have variable's value. include . loads page 1 data .

Comment: [`include()`](http://php.net/include) / [`require()`](http://php.net.require) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316186/how-do-i-share-a-php-variable-between-multiple-pages#25316315

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I share a PHP variable between multiple pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316186/how-do-i-share-a-php-variable-between-multiple-pages)

Comment: thx for your all replies freinds :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the variable in a session and use it on the second page.
This should solve your issue!

```
//For 1.php
$text = "mypassword123and";
$hash = hash('sha256', $text);
session_start();
$_SESSION['hashedValue'] = $hash;

//For 2.php
session_start();
$hash = $_SESSION['hashedValue']
echo $hash
```

Comment: its true . but how can i get var from function? to new page?

Comment: and here . with `$_SESSION['hashedValue']` . we can get the value.
how if i want to get the variable ? `$_SESSION[$test];`
but it wouldnt define in new page :(

Comment: Alex, I couldn't get this part you are talking about. You can set any value in the session variable and you can access it in the application. You can even change them or if you want then you can destroy them as well.